# How can i should handle the injection of service domain?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm building a financial application where i have two ways to calculate the balance of the credit
so i try to follow a design based on Domain Driven Design and i feel some confused respect how supose that i have to inject the balance calculator in the credit entity. 
i try to insert a interface in credit called IBalanceCalculator then when i call method CalculateBalanceAtDate in the credit this determine what instance use

this is the example

```
credit {
  protected  IBalanceCalcultar _calculator;
  ....
    private void _InitializeBalanceCalculator()
    {
        if (_balanceCalculator == null)
            switch (InterestType)
            {
                case EInterestType.OutstandingBalance:
                    _balanceCalculator = new OutstandingBalanceService();
                    break;
                case EInterestType.GlobalBalance:
                    _balanceCalculator = new GlobalBalance();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
    }
    public void CalculateBalanceAtDate(DateTime date, bool moratory)
    {
        _InitializeBalanceCalculator();
        _balanceCalculator.GetBalance(this, date);
    }
}
```

but i feel that this way is not so good

someone can clarify me is correct or if exists a better way

Answer (score 2):

> someone can clarify me is correct or if exists a better way

Sounds like your domain has a concept like an InterestPolicy that determines what strategy should be used to calculate the balance.  Find out what the name of that thing is in your domain (your domain experts will know), and pass it in as an argument

```
public Balance CalculateBalanceAtDate(
    InterestPolicy interestPolicy, 
    DateTime date, 
    bool moratory)
{
    IBalanceCalculator calculator interestPolicy.balanceCalculator(this.interestType)
    return calculator.balance(this, date)
}
```

Slightly better is to take the entity itself out of the equation, and just pass *state*

```
public Balance CalculateBalanceAtDate(
    InterestPolicy interestPolicy, 
    DateTime date, 
    bool moratory)
{
    IBalanceCalculator calculator interestPolicy.balanceCalculator(this.interestType)
    return calculator.balance(this.creditHistory, date)
}
```

Comment: Inspired in your answer i'm thinking eliminate the InterestType attribute of class credit and insted of that put a object called InterestPolicy where inside contains the interestType
for me have sense set the InterestPolicy when i created the credit because the way of how will be calculate the interest shouldn't change in the live of credit

Comment: What about `this.interestType.calculateBalanceAtDate(this.creditHistory, date)`? `InterestType` could just be an enum configured with the proper calculator.

Comment: yes InterestType is a enum and determine how interest will be calculate 
I thought better and is not a attribute of credit now i belive that InterestType  should belong to InterestPolicy because its the entity that determine how interest is calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to inject the service ?

Just pass it as a parameter of your method.

You then wire the whole in your application service at the application level !

Domain Services as a parameter are perfectly fine, it makes your domain object testable as well.

Comment: i think that i should inject the service of balance calculator because it is used in more than one place for example, when i calculate the balance for a report or when a payment is applied to avoid repetitive task of pass the service in each method where is used i prefer inject service.